# How to recursively create .sha256 hash files for every file in a folder?

Tags: find, file-copy, hashsum

Example I have these files

```
/sdcard/testfolder/file1
/sdcard/testfolder/file2
/sdcard/testfolder/file3
/sdcard/testfolder/file4.ext
```

I would like to create .sha256 files for each

```
/sdcard/testfolder/file1.sha256
/sdcard/testfolder/file2.sha256
/sdcard/testfolder/file3.sha256
/sdcard/testfolder/file4.ext.sha256
```

The method should work on every possible valid character in the file names and folder names

My starting point was to try and use find

NOTE : I am using find from "toybox 0.8.0-android" and cannot change it (immutable unrootable file system) however it does seem to be fully featured. My shell is "MirBSD Korn Shell" 2014 https://launchpad.net/mksh and I also cannot change it

```
find /sdcard/testfolder -type file -exec echo {} \;
```

for example returns the file list, one file per line

So one way to do this would be to replace 'echo {}' with equivalent to

```
sha256sum /sdcard/testfolder/file4.ext > /sdcard/testfolder/file4.ext.sha256
```

Maybe something like

```
find /sdcard/testfolder -type file -exec sha256sum {} > {}.sha256 \;
```

Unfortunately, find -exec does not work with that specific syntax.

Looking at an extensive list of find command example

https://sysaix.com/43-practical-examples-of-linux-find-command

I does seem the -exec command parameter1 {} parameter2 ;
is the only format but I could be wrong ?

If possible I would like to keep this as single command

Another avenue might be to pipe into another command, however I can't find how to refer to the filename from  the pipe as a command line argument, maybe not possible ?

```
find /sdcard/testfolder -type file | sort | sha256sum $filename? > $filename?.sha256
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do:

```
find /sdcard/testfolder -not -name '*sha256' -type file -exec sh -c '
    sha256sum "$1" > "$1.sha256"
' sh {} \;
```

Comment: This worked beautifully
I changed it a bit 
find /sdcard/testfolder -type file -exec sh -c ' sha256sum "$1" > "$1.sha256" ' sh {} \;
and here the full result, confirming it works recursively and at least with space characters ! https://i.imgur.com/dvesLpJ.png

Comment: I would add the following improvement, to omit making .sha256 of the .sha256
-not \( -name "*.sha256" \) 
as in 
find /sdcard/testfolder  -not \( -name "*.sha256" \) -type file -exec sh -c ' sha256sum "$1" > "$1.sha256" ' sh {} \;
Thanks !